# deploying web application on server results in this error

Tags: asp.net, iis

```
hello guys i am facing this error
```

[image]

How to fix it.
My ASP.net website is running fine locally.

Comment: how can i read . I man what changes should i made in web.config to read error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Set it to OFF and see what is the error. By default the section is commented in Web.Config. Look for the section custom error in web.config file, uncomment that and set it to off, to see the error on production.

**Update**

```
<system.web> -- inside this section just add the line below. 
                If its already there remove existing custom errors and use this
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: no section is commented in my web.config how to write that section.

Comment: i know that i have to add it at upper part , but dont know the exact syntax .Should i add something like this.                                 <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="/ErrorPages/404.aspx" />
</customErrors>

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of some configuration is different from your local machine and your deployed machine. An error is thrown here because of this. But you actually cannot see the details of the error message because your web.config file probably has customErrors set to be shown only in the local machine or have no custom errors tag. I suggest you turn it to "off" in the web.config file just to see the proper error message on the deployed machine.